# What tag did Javascript addEventListener find

Tags: javascript, html, addeventlistener

I add a Javascript event listener to some html tag. I have to do the same processing on different tags. It would be nice to use a common function.

(1) Is there a way to pass a variable to the function passed to addEventListener.

```
 const theNode = document.querySelector(
  "div.action-bar:not(.usertip-mobile-action-bar) div.dropdown button.button-white");
 theNode.addEventListener("click",
                           processClickReply,
                           false);
```

(2) Would "this" refer to "theNode" in my function processClickReply?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a way to pass a variable to the function passed to addEventListener.

Yes, two ways:

1) by closure (but note that `this` is now `theNode` in the closure, but not in `processClickReply`, so you might want to pass it explicitly - or remember that it is in `evt.target`):

```
let myVar = 84;
theNode.addEventListener(
  "click",
  function(evt) {
    processClickReply(evt, this, myVar);
  },
  false
);
```

2) by binding (where we can explicitly set `this` to `theNode` and `myVar` to the first argument):

```
let myVar = 84;
theNode.addEventListener(
  "click",
  processClickReply.bind(theNode, myVar),
  false
);
```

> Would "this" refer to "theNode" in my function processClickReply?

In your code, it does if `processClickReply` was declared as a traditional function. If it was defined as an arrow function, then no.

In the two methods to pass an argument, you can see how both of them destroy the natural binding of `this`, and which countermeasures can be undertaken to go around it.

Also note that binding and closure will give you different behaviour: if `myVar` is later changed, the change will be reflected in the closure code; but the binding code uses the value of `myVar` at the time.

Answer (score 1):

1: Use an anonymous function:

```
theNode.addEventListener("click", function() { processClickReply(value) }, false);
```

2: Yes